# Creating complex polygon

Tags: javascript, css, math, polygon, clip-path

I have a formula to determine the diameter of a circle, so that, for any given rectangle, the top center and perimeter of the circle touch the top center and bottom corners of the rectangle.

```
diameter = width * width / 4 / height + height // width and height of the rectangle
```

[image]

However, what I now need to do is create a shape like below, which I know can be accomplished with `clip-path: polygon()`, possibly being made even simpler by using the `evenodd` fill-rule of `polygon()`.

[image]

The problem is that I am unfamiliar with `clip-path: polygon` and suck at math, so I am not quite sure if it can be made even simpler by using the `evenodd` fill-rule, let alone how to go about generating the set of vertices to plot.

Obviously, a pure CSS solution is ideal. However, I can use JS if this is impossible to do with CSS alone.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: polygon is not the way to go with this

Comment: @TemaniAfif why not? SVG better?

Comment: because polyong cannot create rounded shape

Comment: @TemaniAfif if there are enough vertices (even though it might be a "million-gon" lol), you can create the illusion of it being round, right?

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you know any lightweight solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A radial-gradient can do the job here:

```css
.box {
  --w:200;
  --h:100;
  --d:calc((var(--w)*var(--w))/(4*var(--h)) + var(--h));
  width:calc(var(--w)*1px);
  height:calc(var(--h)*1px);
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,blue 98%,red) 
    top/calc(var(--d)*1px) calc(var(--d)*1px);
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--w:300"></div>

<div class="box" style="--h:50"></div>
```

Comment: the blue should be transparent, so that we can see whatever lies beneath the rectangle. is this possible? also, they dont seem to be perfect circles, but this might not be a dealbreaker.

Comment: @oldboy change the blue with transparent, it's colors

Comment: noted. is there any way to use viewport units as `--w` and `--h`? the rectangles arent arbitrary shapes, but are representative of portions of the viewport.

Comment: do u mind voting my question up so i can get some other answers?